# Why the Ubuntu upgrade is complaining about the boot loader?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2

I am trying to upgrade ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. While doing so I came across a screen where the upgrade process is asking me to install boot loader, as the previous boot loader don't seem to be present or missing. Its the message on the screen. And, as per the screen suggestion I have selected all the three options mentioned there and clicked on ok. But after couple of minutes I see another screen that says the GRUB failed to install.

[image: screenshot_1]

[image: screenshot_2]

Therefore I click on the "no" on the 2nd screen.

I have attached both screenshots . Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Your upgrade may not work anyway. Regular Ubuntu 16.04 is supported until April 2021, but the light flavours, including Lubuntu, are only supported until April 2019. It is time to do a new install of 18.04 or 20.04. Grub has a file where it stores the original install location, so that must have been another drive.

Answer (score 0):

You must (have) select(ed) `/dev/sda` and left the two other devices unchecked.

Comment: I have checked all of them now. But no result

Comment: Again, you only need to select the first one.

Comment: I got it re-imaged directly by 18.04 image. thanks